# Validation on POST request

Tags: angularjs, express

I am using angular and talking to an express backend.  I can retrieve data from my .get, but my .post is generating a validation error

Client-controller:

```
 $scope.addFriend = function()
    {
        friendsFactory.addFriend($scope.newFriend, function (data)
        {
            $location.url('/friends' + data._id);
        });
    }
```

Client-factory:

```
 factory.addFriend = function (newFriendData, callback) {
        $http.post('/friends', newFriendData)
            .then(function(response)
            {
                console.log(response.data);
                //callback(response.data);
            })
    }
```

Server-route:

```
app.post('/friends', function (request, response) {
        console.log('routes')
        friends.create(request, response);
    })
```

Server-controller:

```
create: function(request, response)
    {
        console.log('request');
        var friendInstance = new Friend();
        friendInstance.first_name = request.params.fname;
        friendInstance.last_name = request.params.lname;
        friendInstance.b_day = request.params.bday;
        friendInstance.save(function(err,data)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                response.json(err);
            }
            else {
                rewponse.json(data);
            }
        })
```

Error on console:

```
Object {errors: Object, message: "Friend validation failed", name: "ValidationError"}
```

Comment: Can you share what Friend looks like?

Comment: first_name: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 20 },
last_name: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 20 },
b_day: { type: Date, required: true }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is most likely a `mongoose` error, the document that you're trying to persist does not follow the Friend schema.

Comment: This is what I was getting at in the comments. @JSim - inspecting your Friend before creation, and comparing it to your schema will probably yield the issue.